# MySQL server crash

Tags: mysql, linux

I am experiencing regular MySQL server crashes (on Linux). After running

```
sudo /etc/init.d/mysql restart
```

the problem goes away, but temporary. It might be one day or couple, but the crash will happen anyway. Here's an excerpt from the error log file, after the crash and before the daemon restart. I am not sure it reflects any useful information though.

```
140511  0:11:06 [Note] Plugin 'FEDERATED' is disabled.
140511  0:11:37  InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, size = 8.0M
140511  0:11:38  InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
InnoDB: The log sequence number in ibdata files does not match
InnoDB: the log sequence number in the ib_logfiles!
140511  0:11:52  InnoDB: Database was not shut down normally!
InnoDB: Starting crash recovery.
InnoDB: Reading tablespace information from the .ibd files...
InnoDB: Restoring possible half-written data pages from the doublewrite
InnoDB: buffer...
140511  0:14:26  InnoDB: Started; log sequence number 1 3968482280
140511  0:16:46 [Note] Event Scheduler: Loaded 0 events
140511  0:16:46 [Note] /usr/sbin/mysqld: ready for connections.
Version: '5.1.69-0ubuntu0.11.10.1'  socket: '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock'  port: 3306  (Ubuntu)
140511  0:22:00 [Note] Plugin 'FEDERATED' is disabled.
140511  0:22:46  InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, size = 8.0M
140511  0:22:46  InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
InnoDB: The log sequence number in ibdata files does not match
InnoDB: the log sequence number in the ib_logfiles!
140511  0:22:52  InnoDB: Database was not shut down normally!
InnoDB: Starting crash recovery.
InnoDB: Reading tablespace information from the .ibd files...
InnoDB: Restoring possible half-written data pages from the doublewrite
InnoDB: buffer...
140511  0:24:41  InnoDB: Started; log sequence number 1 3968482290
140511  0:26:55 [Note] Event Scheduler: Loaded 0 events
140511  0:26:56 [Note] /usr/sbin/mysqld: ready for connections.
Version: '5.1.69-0ubuntu0.11.10.1'  socket: '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock'  port: 3306  (Ubuntu)
```

The problem did not disappear after reinstalling the server.

Perhaps it's time to install the database on clean OS install, and bring all my databases there, but before such time-consuming solution I'd like to try some less-involving ones, if there are any.

Comment: What about the actual memory. I had a win 7 running for years, but win8 refused to install starting memory issues.  You could simply just swap them around on b the board and see if it still happens based on b the same resource situation

Comment: Have you tried repairing the tables? See: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/rebuilding-tables.html Also, are you running any type of replication or duplications? Also, how big is the database and are you running out of disk space?

Comment: No replication or duplications. The free disk space if around 500Mb. Not too much, but not too shabby either. I am wondering why the error log does not provide more useful info.

Comment: @WilsonHauck this is an old problem that was eventually "solved" by moving the services to another server with fresh OS install.

Comment: @Passiday  My offer is still valid, for server tuning analysis if you are running MySQL of some flavor.  Thanks